# Issues in using update query on page submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

I don't know where am getting wrong with all these codes. I am trying to edit/update the HTML form on submit. Let me brief it;

-We have a search html from where we have achieved successful search. [search.php]

-After this ,based on search.php, we are viewing the results from database which is too a success [view.php]

- Now the problem is here, in [view.php] we have 2 buttons viz; Edit and Update.
- After on "Edit" click the displayed values are being placed in text box to edit the values/result.
- Now the problem is too with "Update",as soon we hit "Update" button the page is being refreshed and the values are being disappeared [its the previously fetched results from db] and its showing "query is empty"

I don't know where I am going wrong.

```
<?php
//All database connection is done successfull and sql query is too fine for me.
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "in result";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
 $viewrecruiter0=$row['recruiter_did'];
 $viewrecruiter1=$row['recruiter_name'];    
 $viewrecruiter2=$row['recruiter_mobile'];
} 

?>   

<form name="form4" method="POST" action='viewrecruiter.php?var=<?php echo urlencode($viewrecruiter0);?>'>

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2">
          <label for="Recruiter Name">Recruiter code :</label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2">
          <?php echo $viewrecruiter0; ?>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2">
       <label for="Recruiter Name">Recruiter Name :</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-2 f1">
       <?php echo $viewrecruiter1; ?>
     </div>
    <div class="f2">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recruiter_v_by_name" name="recruiter_v_by_name" value="<?php echo $viewrecruiter1;?>">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2">
         <label for="Recruiter Name">Recruiter Mail :</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 f1">
         <?php echo $viewrecruiter2; ?>
      </div>
       <div class="f2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recruiter_v_by_mail" name="recruiter_v_by_mail" value="<?php echo $viewrecruiter2;?>">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">                                             
    <input type="button" id="recruiter_v_btn1" name="recruiter_v_btn1" value="Edit" class="btn2 btn-primary show" style="margin-left:316px"> 
</div>

<?php   
  if (isset($_GET['var']))
  {
    $id1=$_GET['var'];
    echo $id1;
  }
?>

<input type="submit" id="recruiter_v_btn2" name="recruiter_v_btn2" value="Update" class="btn2 btn-primary"  style="margin-top:-1px">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['recruiter_v_btn2']))
    {

     $query1="UPDATE recruiter,recruiter_details SET recruiter.recruiter_name='".$_POST['recruiter_v_by_name']."'".",recruiter.recruiter_mobile='".$_POST['recruiter_v_by_mail']."'"." where recruiter.recruiter_num=recruiter_details.recruiter_did AND recruiter.recruiter_num=".$id1;

  mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
   }
?>
  </form>
```

We are passing recruiter code through query string on same page as written in .
I think on clicking on "Update" button page is getting refresh and its not getting search query result, that's why its showing "Query is empty".

Comment: You should separate your design code from your backend code--check out "smarty" templating system.  This will make finding errors much easier.

Comment: @PhyllisSutherland.... Thank you for your suggestion, but its just a small piece of SQl code thats why we are implementing on same page.